# How can i pass to which function string with logical expresion in R?

Tags: r, dataset, subset, logical-operators

I want to make data subset with logical expression i have stored in string, like this:

```
logical_var = paste0("input_dataset$","heigth >= 1.60")
```

but i cant use it as

```
subset_data <- input_dataset[ which(logical_var), ]
```

or

```
subset_data <- input_dataset[ which(as.logical(logical_var)), ]
```

because it makes obvious syntax error. From documentation i understand, that wchich() takes only logical expressions.

The effect I want to get would be as in such expression:

```
subset_data <- input_dataset[ which(input_dataset$heigth >= 1.60), ]
```

but I don't know the selection condition in advance, I read it from a specific variable.

What should i do with it?

Comment: can you `dput(df) ` small subset of your dataframe

Comment: The answer to evaluating text of code is to use `eval(parse(text=...))`, but asking to do that is usually indicative of trying to solve the wrong problem or the right problem in a discouraged way. (The use of `eval`/`parse` can be slow and is prone to so many problems and troubleshooting issues.) What is it you ultimately have and need?

Answer (score 1):

`eval(str2lang())` is one way to do it:

`str2lang` is a shortcut for `parse(text = ..., source = FALSE)` which is another option.

```r
logical_var = paste0("iris$","Sepal.Length >= 6.5")

iris[eval(str2lang(logical_var)),]

#>     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
#> 51           7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor
#> 53           6.9         3.1          4.9         1.5 versicolor
#> 55           6.5         2.8          4.6         1.5 versicolor
#> 59           6.6         2.9          4.6         1.3 versicolor
#> 66           6.7         3.1          4.4         1.4 versicolor
#> 76           6.6         3.0          4.4         1.4 versicolor
#> 77           6.8         2.8          4.8         1.4 versicolor
#> 78           6.7         3.0          5.0         1.7 versicolor
#> 87           6.7         3.1          4.7         1.5 versicolor
#> 103          7.1         3.0          5.9         2.1  virginica
#> 105          6.5         3.0          5.8         2.2  virginica
#> 106          7.6         3.0          6.6         2.1  virginica
#> 108          7.3         2.9          6.3         1.8  virginica
#> 109          6.7         2.5          5.8         1.8  virginica
#> 110          7.2         3.6          6.1         2.5  virginica
#> 111          6.5         3.2          5.1         2.0  virginica
#> 113          6.8         3.0          5.5         2.1  virginica
#> 117          6.5         3.0          5.5         1.8  virginica
#> 118          7.7         3.8          6.7         2.2  virginica
#> 119          7.7         2.6          6.9         2.3  virginica
#> 121          6.9         3.2          5.7         2.3  virginica
#> 123          7.7         2.8          6.7         2.0  virginica
#> 125          6.7         3.3          5.7         2.1  virginica
#> 126          7.2         3.2          6.0         1.8  virginica
#> 130          7.2         3.0          5.8         1.6  virginica
#> 131          7.4         2.8          6.1         1.9  virginica
#> 132          7.9         3.8          6.4         2.0  virginica
#> 136          7.7         3.0          6.1         2.3  virginica
#> 140          6.9         3.1          5.4         2.1  virginica
#> 141          6.7         3.1          5.6         2.4  virginica
#> 142          6.9         3.1          5.1         2.3  virginica
#> 144          6.8         3.2          5.9         2.3  virginica
#> 145          6.7         3.3          5.7         2.5  virginica
#> 146          6.7         3.0          5.2         2.3  virginica
#> 148          6.5         3.0          5.2         2.0  virginica
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

You can also wrap it in `which()` for the handling of `NA`'s.

```r
iris[which(eval(str2lang(logical_var))),]
```

Comment: Great, works! :) Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

**1) do.call/subset/parse** Use do.call/subset/parse like this.  It does not use eval or any packages.

```
Subset <- function(data, cond) {
  do.call("subset", list(data, parse(text = cond)))
}

# test
Subset(iris, "Sepal.Length > 5.5 & Species == 'setosa'")
```

giving:

```
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
15          5.8         4.0          1.2         0.2  setosa
16          5.7         4.4          1.5         0.4  setosa
19          5.7         3.8          1.7         0.3  setosa
>
```

**2) sql** If we specify the condition using SQL syntax then it can be done like this.  We surrounded Sepal.Length with square brackets since otherwise dot is an SQL operator.  The output is the same as above.

```
library(sqldf)
Subset2 <- function(data, cond) {
  fn$sqldf("select * from data where $cond")
}
Subset2(iris, "[Sepal.Length] > 5.5 and Species == 'setosa'")
```